# Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting this error whenever I run npm start
I have post in my index file as follows:

```
app.post('/api/actions',db.validateAction, db.createAction);
```

Then I have the validationAction and createAction in my queries.js:

```
 21 function validateAction(req, res, next) {
 22 
 25   req.checkBody('dateDone', 'Invalid date').notEmpty();
 27   req.checkBody('completed', 'Invalid completed value').isBoolean();
 29 
 30   var errors = req.validationErrors();
 31 
 32   if (errors) {
 33     var response = { errors: [] };
 34     errors.forEach(function(err) {
 35       response.errors.push(err.msg);
 36     });
 37     res.statusCode = 400;
 38     return res.json(response);
 39   }
 40   return next();
 41 }

128 function createAction(req, res, next) { 
129   pool.connect(function(err,client,done) {
130 
131     if(err){
132       console.log("Not able to get connection "+ err + "\n");
133       res.status(400).send(err);
134     }
135 
136     var sql = 'INSERT INTO acts(dateDone, completed) VALUES($1,$2) RETURNING id';
137 
138     var data = [
141       req.body.dateDone,
143       req.body.completed,
145     ]
146 
147     client.query(sql, data, function(err, result) {
148 
149       if (err) {
150         console.error(err);
151         res.statusCode = 500;
152         return res.json({
153           errors: ['Failed to create action']
154         });
155       }
156 
157       // get new action
158       var newActionId = result.rows[0].id;
159       var sql = 'SELECT * FROM acts WHERE id = $1';
160 
161       client.query(sql, [newActionId], function(err, result) {
162 
163         if (err) {
164           console.error(err);
165           res.statusCode = 500;
166           return res.json({
167             errors: ['Could not retrieve action after create']
168           });
169         }
170 
171         console.log("Successfully created action");
172         // The request created a new resource object
173         res.status(201).json({
174           status: 'Success',
175           data: result.rows[0],
176           message: 'Created new action'
177         });
178       });
179     });
180   });
181 }
```

I had my POST function working perfectly but now once I tried to add this validation it does not work. I injected the middleware (validateAction) before the route handler as I learned was the proper way to do it so I am unsure of why this is working.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you properly exporting and importing the functions?

Comment: @Svenskunganka Sorry, I'm new to JS, what does that mean?

Comment: `app.post('/api/actions',[db.validateAction, db.createAction]);`

Comment: @user9449018 I'm refering to your `module.exports = ...` and `var db = require(...)`. Basically make sure that your `db` object actually contains the two functions that you pass to the route.

Comment: @Svenskunganka Thank you so much! Turns out I hadn't added the new function to the exports